# How can I automatically pass variables out of the function? How to pass variables from inner to the outer scope?

Tags: python, julia

I do a project in Python and Julia and have codes within functions such as (Julia version):

```
function foo(a,b)
    c = a+b
    #more code here
end
```

or (Python version)

```
def foo(a,b):
    c=a+b
    #more code here
```

Then I need to test these functions by checking the values of the variables in there (within the function scope).
I would like to avoid to write `print(variables)` or `return variables` every time.
Is there any way in that helps me automatically pass all the variables onto the outer scope so the developing environment so that I can easily check them?

Comment: Please pick on language. Asking for solutions for multiple languages makes your question unfocussed, and may therefor be closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking"? You should write proper unit tests for functions, not manually inspect/print variables

Comment: You could look into unit testing. It won't help with your laziness to return variables, but once you do that, it saves you the trouble of manually checking.

Comment: "I'm too lazy to write ``print(variables)`` or ``return variables``." Just to be clear: You are looking for a solution that doesn't require you to ``print`` or ``return`` *anything*?

Comment: I have edited this question so maybe now, despite being "two language question" it can be interesting to know the differences as in many scenarios Python and Julia are being used together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Julia you can use `Base.@locals` macro such as:

```
function foo(a,b)
   c = a+b
   @show Base.@locals
end
```

`Base.@locals` returns a `Dict` with all local variables and I used here `@show` to show it. Let's run a test:

```
julia> foo(10,15)
#= REPL[2]:3 =# Base.@locals() = Dict{Symbol, Any}(:a => 10, :b => 15, :c => 25)
Dict{Symbol, Any} with 3 entries:
  :a => 10
  :b => 15
  :c => 25
```

In Python there is a very similar `locals()` function such as:

```
def foo(a,b):
    c=a+b
    print(locals())
```

Now let us test it:

```
>>> foo(10,15)
{'a': 10, 'b': 15, 'c': 25}
```

If you want rather to export the variables to global scope in Julia you can do:

```
function foo(a,b)
    c = a+b
    Main.eval.(:($key = $value) for (key,value) in Base.@locals)
end
```

This copies the values of `a,b,c` to the `Main` scope:

```
julia> foo(200,300);

julia> a,b,c
(200, 300, 500)
```

Python has no meta-programming but you can just do (suggested by @MisterMiyagi):

```
globals().update(locals())
```

Comment: For Python, one can just ``globals().update(locals())`` to achieve Julia's ``Main.eval`` effect (give or take a typo).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi   great!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Obviously I asked a very vague question, but your answer really helps. Now I can check the variable values when i finished executing functions.:)